# python matplotlib.plot does not show chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

Have recently started playing with Python. I have installed Python Spyder app on the Mac. Everything has been working well until recently for some reason the matplotlib charts stopped displaying. A simple code like this does  not work anymore:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(0.4 * np.pi, 100)
plt.plot(x)
```

The only output is 
    []

I have Spyder 2.3.3, Python 3.4.3 64 Bit.

Comment: Sorry the only output is "[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x116c6f160>]"

Comment: When you look at the code for the examples in the gallery, can you see what yours is missing?

Answer (score 3):

You have to tell the plot to show itself with:

`plt.show()`